# AWS EC2 instance import ACM generated certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, jwt

We have a RESTful webservices application running on AWS EC2 instance.We have a requirement for calling a third party api,which needs JWT token signed with CA certificate to trust our api call.We have created CA certificate using Amazon certificate manager and imported it in Amazon ELB containing the ec2 instance. How can we access the private key of the certificate from our application for signing the JWT token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access the private key for the certificates stored in ACM. You will need to acquire a CA certificate for signing the JWT. Then install the certificate on your EC2 instance so that the signing code can access it.